# What is the integral of $\int_{-1}^1 e^{2 \pi i \beta z} dz$?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

I am getting confused with how to compute $I = \int_{-1}^1 e^{2 \pi i \beta z} dz$. 
Here $0 \not = \beta \in \mathbb{R}$. 
Is 
$$
I = \frac{1}{2 \pi i \beta}(e^{2 \pi i \beta} - e^{-2 \pi i \beta}),
$$
or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your calculation is right. You may rewrite the result as $\frac{1}{\pi\beta}\sin(2\pi\beta)$. Another option is $2\operatorname{sinc}(2\pi\beta)$, which is also correct if $\beta=0$; that's a nice sanity check.